# How do Factory Functions make things private?

Tags: javascript

If we have a Factory Function like the one down below. Why is the inner variable `bark` private to changes outside?

```
  var dog = function(){
      var bark = "Woof"        //What makes this private?
      return {
        talk: function(){
          console.log(bark)
        }
      }
    }
    var fido = dog()   
    fido.bark = "BARK BARK"    //Why does this not change the bark inside the function? 
    fido.talk()
```

Comment: Why would you expect it to change? How the JS engine could magically determine that `fido.bark` is related to the local variable `bark` of the `dog` function?

Comment: @plalx I think he's just trying to learn why the factory pattern allow one to have private variables.

Comment: Because bark is not a property of fido. (try to put this.bark = "Woof" and console.log(this.bark);), also a function creates a new scope and var bark is not accesible from outside.

Comment: They are private because vars declared in a JS function are private, it's just normal JS scoping. The better question is why `talk` is **not** private. That's the cool part about this piece of code.

Comment: @dlsso because you are returning an object that contains that function, and that function contains a reference to bark variable.

Comment: @plalx If I were a beginner I would answer "Because fido is the dog function." He probably needs assignment explained for your comment to make sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot access the bark property on the object returned by the factory function simply because the object returned does not have that property. Let me explain.

Consider this small change in your factory function. I've broken down that return statement into two statements.

```
var dog = function(){
  var bark = "Woof";
  var returnObject = {
    talk: function(){
      console.log(bark)
    }
  };
  return returnObject;
}
```

Now, look carefully at the `returnObject` variable just before the return statement. It does not have a `bark` property. Just a talk method. Remember, this is the object that is returned in the end so accesing or editing bark property on this returned object will have no effect on the internal bark value.

You might be wondering how the `talk` method can access the internal bark variable. That `talk` method can access the internal `bark` variable due to a concept called 'closure' in JavaScript. You should read more on it. An excellent resource on closures is [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work?rq=1) right here on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1):

The key idea here is that when a function references a variable from an outer scope - for example in this case the `talk` function is referencing the `bark` variable which comes from the outer scope - that's called a closure.

The variable is held by the function itself and, by design of the language, can't be directly accessed by the "outside world".  It's only accessible by the outside world if you choose to expose it, for example as part of the return value from the function.

If you wanted a version where `bark` could be changed, you would have to do  something like this:

```
var dog = function(){
  var theDog = {
    bark: "bark",
    talk: function() {
      console.log(this.bark);
    }
  };
  return theDog;
}
var fido = dog()   
fido.bark = "BARK BARK"    //Why does this not change the bark inside the function? 
fido.talk()
```

(A more idiomatic version would likely use a `Dog` constructor function but I'm trying to keep it as close to the original code as possible)

The [MDN article on closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) is quite good for more information on closures.

Answer (score 0):

The variable bark available within the function.to make it public it is necessary to assign it to this.

```
var dog = function(){
      this.bark = "Woof"
      return {
        talk: function(){
          console.log(this.bark)
        }
      }
    }
    var fido = dog()   
    fido.bark = "BARK BARK"
    fido.talk()
```

or to transfer his data through the constructor

```
var dog = function(data){
      if(!data) data = 'Woof';
      var bark = data;
......
......
```